# Плагин слайдера Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть готовая фронт часть, но теперь наступает время самого интересного, и я просто не могу решить с чего начать.

Пока рассматриваю вариант с плагином Advanced Custom Fields. Мне по сути нужно 3 поля, одно поле для ввода дескрипции, второе поле для добавления линка к посту, и третье поле собственно для картинки. Естественно в каждом слайде все должно быть индивидуальным, подскажите пожалуйста знатоки, с какой стороны к этому подойти и нужно ли вообще придумывать велосипед с этим плагином или можно как-то проще?

ЗЫ. Решение по поводу написанию своего, а не использованию того же метаслайдера, пришло в свете немного кастомного функционала...

ЗЫЫ. буду благодарен за любые подсказки, даже если кинете не тривиальную статью с wp-kama

Comment: ACF Repeater или создавать кастомный тип записи и добавлять мета-боксы.

Comment: метаслайдер - это убогое убожество. Есть масса более функциональных плагов. Зачем плодить сущности и дыры.

Comment: Решил не далеко отходить от своего плана, и просто использовал ACF + FlexSlider + Категории вордпресса. Спасибо всем за советы!

Answer (score 2):

У меня когда-то стояла подобная задача, я использовал ACF PRO и [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

В ACF PRO есть [Repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/), в него один раз добавляются 3 поля, а потом можно делать сколько угодно слайдов.

Потом просто получать все слайды из Repeater и выводить через while внутри div. Через JS в этом div инициализируется Slick, он довольно простой, но неплохо кастомизируется, есть автоплей с настраиваемым временем, стрелки, точки и прочие вещи присущие слайдеру. Внешний вид слайдера меняется через CSS и под любой дизайн можно подогнать.

Если Ваш кастомный функционал сюда впишется, то на мой взгляд это наиболее простое решение

Answer (score 1):

Писать свой плагин, который будет нуждаться в другом плагине - плохой вариант. Тем более, что нужно всего 3 поля, которые можно сделать и самому.

Последовательность действий такая:

1. Проще всего, если слайдер будет создан как тип записей, например "best_ever_slider". Где каждая запись - отдельный слайд.

   - https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type (обязательно использовать параметры publicly_queryable и exclude_from_search, чтобы скрыть от индексации этот тип записей). Так же не забыть обновить "постоянные ссылки" после создания.
2. Далее для типа записей нужно добавить произвольные поля

   - https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_meta_box
   - создаем свои поля, получаем данные в них с помощью https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_meta
3. Далее реализуем механизм сохранения данных

   - https://wp-kama.ru/hook/save_post
4. Для разделения слайдов можно использовать таксономии, для этого регистрируем свою и подвязываем к нашему типу записей

   - https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_taxonomy
5. Для получения слайдов можно использовать:

   - https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts
   - https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query (сложнее, но даёт больше возможностей)
   - можно всё это реализовать через shortcode https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_shortcode

Это всё в том случае, если пишете свой плагин. Для остальных случаев - используйте готовые решения. Slick slider plugin или ACF + Repeater(PRO) значительно упрощает эту задачу.